# Images are not showing on Heroku on RoR project using ImageMagick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have built my first Ruby on Rails app to be deployed on Heroku; however, my images are not showing up. I am using the ImageMagick gem, and have noticed now that even my stars (5 star rating ability) are not showing.

I am new to Ruby on Rails and Heroku, and cannot figure out how to debug the problem. I did use the Production group: 'PG' and the log notes in Heroku state the Postgresql database has been attached.

https://true-marks-57891.herokuapp.com/

Comment: Are you using something like Carrierwave or Paperclip to upload the images? I don't use Heroku but you might want to consider storing your images elsewhere like AWS S3. You can still use Heroku to host your app but store the images on a dedicated storage provider.

Comment: Yes I am using PaperClip to upload the images. I will look into the AWS option. Thank you